# How do I overlap UIImageView and UIView without adding the alphas?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UICollectionView where each cell contains a UIImageView, with an image that (sometimes) has an alpha of 0.2. These cells are connected with a supplementary view (UICollectionReusableView) that has a background color with an alpha of 0.2. Where these two pieces overlap, the alphas are added and the result is an alpha of 0.4.

[image: Overlapping alphas]

How do I overlap these two pieces while retaining the 0.2 alpha?